# UWP Measure UI Element in Background Thread

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

I am trying to measure UI elements but don't want to add them to the visual tree. Is there ANY way that I can do this without dispatching to the UI thread?

For example - I have some code that needs to know how big a button with the text "Foo Button" in it with a certain font size, padding, etc. The kicker is, once I know the theortical size of that Button, I don't need it anymore.

Anytime I even try to create an instance of a Button (or any UIElement for that matter) I get a thread access exception.

My guess is there's no way around this but I'm really hoping I'm wrong!

Comment: I wonder if this might not be an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would your code need to know such a thing?

Comment: Nobody thinks it's an XY problem. True, sometimes it really isn't. Can you explain why this is the only possible solution?

Comment: Well, anyway, if you're having trouble creating UI elements in a non-UI thread, and you're not willing to contemplate any other solutions or tell anybody enough that they could even guess at other ways to solve the essential problem, I'd share enough code for people to figure out how to stop getting the exception you're getting. There's nothing mysterious about that stuff.

Comment: You're not even reading my comments. Good luck.

Comment: You can create items in separate thread but will not be able to add them to existing UI thread but if you e.g create new UI window from the same thread as the ui elements you will be able to add the to it